# macOS Big Sur - how to show exact time when clicking on analog clock in the menu bar?

Tags: menu-bar, big-sur, clock

I just upgraded to macOS Big Sur and this is my menu bar and the analog clock is at the end:

[image]

When I click on the analog clock, notifications and widgets are shown, while in Catalina, the exact time would be shown. How do I do that in Big Sur?

Comment: It looks like the only option to see the time when using an analog clock is to either add a **Clock** _widget_, or set one of the clocks on the **World Clock** _widget_ to a city in your time zone.

Comment: I wish we didn't have to be stuck with widgets at all, but they could at least give us the option to right-justify them so there isn't an awkward gap next to the clock when you use it.